# bash - uppercase first characters after underscore

Tags: bash

I want to uppercase the first character and each  first character after underscore. For example:

```
foo="text_search";

//uppercase first characters

echo $foo;
```

should output "Text_Search"

I have tried the following:

```
UCF_textSearch=${foo^}

echo UCF_textSearch
```

but it outputs "Text_search" instead of "Text_Search".

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution utilizing GNU sed:

```
foo="the_quick_brown_dog"
foo=$(echo "$foo" | sed -e 's/\(^\|_\)\([a-z]\)/\1\u\2/g')
echo $foo
```

Result:

```
$ ./test.sh
The_Quick_Brown_Dog
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a mixture of bash and sed in your script to make a function:

```
foo="text_search";

uppercase() {
    echo "${1^}" | sed 's/_\([a-z]\)/_\u\1/g'
}

foo=$(uppercase "$foo")

echo "$foo" # => Text_Search
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac then you may need to use gsed.

```
$ echo $foo | gsed 's/\(\(_\|^\).\)/\U\1/g
```